# The parser does not write to json. Writes only {}

Tags: python, json, parsing

I created a market parser for my own purposes, it works well overall!

Initially faced with a recording problem, gave a decode error. Now he did something and it disappeared, but now he does not want to parse the data into json, but simply writes 2 characters - {}

Here is main.py:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_first_news():
    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36"
    }

    url = "https://funpay.ru/lots/700/"
    r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    articles_cards = soup.find_all("a", class_="tc-desc-text")

    news_dict = {}
    for article in articles_cards:
        article_title = article.find("div", class_="tc-desc-text").text.strip()
        article_desc = article.find("div", class_="tc-price").text.strip()
        article_url = f'https://funpay.ru/lots/700/{article.get("href")}'

        article_id = article_url.split("=")[-1]

        # print(f"{article_title} | {article_url} | {article_date_timestamp}")

        news_dict[article_id] = {
            "article_title": article_title,
            "article_url": article_url,
            "article_desc": article_desc
        }

    with open("news_dict.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(news_dict, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)


def main():
    get_first_news()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is test.py

```
# url = "https://www.securitylab.ru/news/520908.php"
#
# article_id = url.split("/")[-1]
# article_id = article_id[:-4]
# print(article_id)
import json

with open("news_dict.json") as file:
    news_dict = json.load(file)

search_id = "520908123"

if search_id in news_dict:
    print("Новость уже есть в словаре, пропускаем итерацию")
else:
    print("Свежая новость, добавляем в словарь")
```

Here is news_dict.json:

```
{}
```

Comment: the most obvious issue would just be `soup.find_all("a", class_="tc-desc-text")` not finding anything. what does it print when you uncomment your debugging statement?

Comment: @MichaelSpeer , I solved another problem, but when recording, incomprehensible characters appeared, look - https://imgur.com/a/JCxnPnJ

Comment: That sounds like an issue with your editor. Given that the page is `.ru`, my guess is the text contains a lot of non-ASCII characters and that your editor hasn't been configured to handle them correctly. Regardless, if you've solved the problem, either edit your question to reflect the new problem or (preferably) post an answer and then make a new question.

Comment: thank you so much! How do I close this question?

Answer (score 0):

In article_cards = soup.find_all ("a", class _ = "tc-desc-text"),
we replace "a" with "div"
Here's what should come out:
article_cards = soup.find_all ("div", class _ = "tc-desc-text")